# training linear layers: collectively vs individually

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am making a tensorflow model to output a row of transition probabilitites from a given source node to a given set of other nodes. The model takes transition specific input information and passes it to a selected linear layer. This linear layer is specific to the given source node, meaning that each source node has its own linear layer. This is what the model looks like:

```
class GetLinearLayer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.layer_weights = self.add_weight(shape=(num_layers, 15),
                                             initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                             trainable=True,
                                             name='layer_weights')
        self.layer_bias = self.add_weight(shape=(num_layers, 1),
                                          initializer='zeros',
                                          trainable=True,
                                          name='layer_bias')

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs, source):
        selected_weights = tf.gather(self.layer_weights, source)
        selected_bias = tf.gather(self.layer_bias, source)

        # Expand the dimensions of selected_weights and selected_bias to match inputs
        selected_weights = tf.expand_dims(selected_weights, axis=1)
        selected_bias = tf.expand_dims(selected_bias, axis=1)

        # Compute the output directly
        outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, selected_weights, transpose_b=True) + selected_bias

        return outputs
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = {}
        config.update({
            'num_layers': self.num_layers,
        })
        return config

    
    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)

xstation = Input(shape=(None,17))
xfrom = Input(shape=(None,5))
x2 = Input(shape=(None,5))
xdiff = Input(shape=(None,5))
xdiffof1 = Input(shape=(None,5))
xpad = Input(shape=(None,1))
xmark = Input(shape=(None,1))
xmarksym = Input(shape=(None,1))
xstat = Input(shape=(None,1))
xstatsym = Input(shape=(None,1))
xsource = Input(shape=(None,1))

source = tf.squeeze(xsource[:, 0, :], axis=-1)
source = tf.cast(source, dtype=tf.int32)

get_linear_layer_obj = GetLinearLayer(num_layers=8908)

conc_linear = tf.concat([ xdiff, xdiffof1, xmark, xmarksym, xstat, xstatsym, xpad], axis=2)

outputs_seq = get_linear_layer_obj(conc_linear, source)

softmax_outputs = Softmax(axis=1)(outputs_seq)

modified_output = tf.squeeze(softmax_outputs, axis=-1)

model_custom = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[xstation, xfrom, x2, xdiff, xdiffof1, xpad, xmark, xmarksym,xstat,xstatsym, xsource], outputs=modified_output)
model_custom.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(axis = 1))
```

This is what the architecture looks like schematically (you can neglect the stacked dense layers):

[image]

I trained this model with a training and validation set with the following code:

```
train_Xstation = np.array(df_padded['Xstation'].tolist())
train_Xfrom = np.array(df_padded['Xfrom'].tolist())
train_X2 = np.array(df_padded['X2'].tolist())
train_Xdiff = np.array(df_padded['Xdiff'].tolist())
train_Xdiffof1 = np.array(df_padded['Xdiffof1'].tolist())
train_Xpad = np.array(df_padded['Xpad'].tolist())
train_Xsource = np.array(df_padded['Xsource'].tolist())

train_Ybin = np.array(df_padded['Ybin'].tolist())
train_Ybinsym = np.array(df_padded['Ybinsym'].tolist())

train_Ymark = np.array(df_padded['Ymark'].tolist())
train_Ymarksym = np.array(df_padded['Ymarksym'].tolist())
train_Ystat = np.array(df_padded['Ystat'].tolist())
train_Ystatsym = np.array(df_padded['Ystatsym'].tolist())

train_X = [train_Xstation, train_Xfrom, train_X2, train_Xdiff,train_Xdiffof1, train_Xpad, train_Ymark, train_Ymarksym, train_Ystat, train_Ystatsym, train_Xsource]

train_W = np.array(df_padded['W'].tolist())

val_Xstation = np.array(val_df_padded['Xstation'].tolist())
val_Xfrom = np.array(val_df_padded['Xfrom'].tolist())
val_X2 = np.array(val_df_padded['X2'].tolist())
val_Xdiff = np.array(val_df_padded['Xdiff'].tolist())
val_Xdiffof1 = np.array(val_df_padded['Xdiffof1'].tolist())
val_Xpad = np.array(val_df_padded['Xpad'].tolist())
val_Xsource = np.array(val_df_padded['Xsource'].tolist())

val_Ybin = np.array(val_df_padded['Ybin'].tolist())
val_Ybinsym = np.array(val_df_padded['Ybinsym'].tolist())
val_Ymark = np.array(val_df_padded['Ymark'].tolist())
val_Ymarksym = np.array(val_df_padded['Ymarksym'].tolist())
val_Ystat = np.array(val_df_padded['Ystat'].tolist())
val_Ystatsym = np.array(val_df_padded['Ystatsym'].tolist())

val_X = [val_Xstation, val_Xfrom, val_X2, val_Xdiff,val_Xdiffof1, val_Xpad, val_Ymark, val_Ymarksym,val_Ystat, val_Ystatsym, val_Xsource]

val_W = np.array(val_df_padded['W'].tolist())
```

```
t1 = time.time()
model_custom.fit(train_X, train_Ybinsym, sample_weight=train_W, epochs=25, batch_size=32, validation_data=(val_X, val_Ybinsym))
t2 = time.time()
t2-t1
```

At epoch 25 the minimal val_loss was reached with a value of 1.8106 (I know this because I also tried for 50 epochs).

Then I thought would it not be better to train each linear layer individually with its own training and validation data? This way each layer trains for a different amount of epochs and reaches its own minimal validation loss. They do not share any weights anyways. So I tried this with this code:

Preparing the data (only the data from sources present in the validation set):

```
val_df_sources = set()
for source in val_df['Xsource']:
    val_df_sources.add(source)
print(len(val_df_sources))

training_datX = []
training_datY = []
training_datW = []
val_datX = []
val_datY = []

i = 1
for source in val_df_sources:
    print('Iteration: ', i, 'Source: ', source)
    df_padded_filtered = df_padded[df_padded['Xsource_single'] == source]
    val_df_padded_filtered = val_df_padded[val_df_padded['Xsource_single'] == source]
    
    ## Training data
    train_Xstation = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Xstation'].tolist())
    train_Xfrom = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Xfrom'].tolist())
    train_X2 = np.array(df_padded_filtered['X2'].tolist())
    train_Xdiff = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Xdiff'].tolist())
    train_Xdiffof1 = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Xdiffof1'].tolist())
    train_Xpad = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Xpad'].tolist())
    train_Xsource = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Xsource'].tolist())
    
    train_Ybin = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Ybin'].tolist())
    train_Ybinsym = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Ybinsym'].tolist())
    
    train_Ymark = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Ymark'].tolist())
    train_Ymarksym = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Ymarksym'].tolist())
    train_Ystat = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Ystat'].tolist())
    train_Ystatsym = np.array(df_padded_filtered['Ystatsym'].tolist())
    
    train_X = [train_Xstation, train_Xfrom, train_X2, train_Xdiff,train_Xdiffof1, train_Xpad, train_Ymark, train_Ymarksym, train_Ystat, train_Ystatsym, train_Xsource]
    
    train_W = np.array(df_padded_filtered['W'].tolist())
    
    ## Validation data
    val_Xstation = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Xstation'].tolist())
    val_Xfrom = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Xfrom'].tolist())
    val_X2 = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['X2'].tolist())
    val_Xdiff = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Xdiff'].tolist())
    val_Xdiffof1 = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Xdiffof1'].tolist())
    val_Xpad = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Xpad'].tolist())
    val_Xsource = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Xsource'].tolist())
    
    val_Ybin = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Ybin'].tolist())
    val_Ybinsym = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Ybinsym'].tolist())
    val_Ymark = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Ymark'].tolist())
    val_Ymarksym = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Ymarksym'].tolist())
    val_Ystat = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Ystat'].tolist())
    val_Ystatsym = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['Ystatsym'].tolist())
    
    val_X = [val_Xstation, val_Xfrom, val_X2, val_Xdiff,val_Xdiffof1, val_Xpad, val_Ymark, val_Ymarksym,val_Ystat, val_Ystatsym, val_Xsource]
    
    val_W = np.array(val_df_padded_filtered['W'].tolist())
    
    training_datX.append(train_X)
    training_datY.append(train_Ybinsym)
    training_datW.append(train_W)
    
    val_datX.append(val_X)
    val_datY.append(val_Ybinsym)
    i +=1
```

```
eval_Xstation = np.array(val_df_padded['Xstation'].tolist())
eval_Xfrom = np.array(val_df_padded['Xfrom'].tolist())
eval_X2 = np.array(val_df_padded['X2'].tolist())
eval_Xdiff = np.array(val_df_padded['Xdiff'].tolist())
eval_Xdiffof1 = np.array(val_df_padded['Xdiffof1'].tolist())
eval_Xpad = np.array(val_df_padded['Xpad'].tolist())
eval_Xsource = np.array(val_df_padded['Xsource'].tolist())

eval_Ybin = np.array(val_df_padded['Ybin'].tolist())
eval_Ybinsym = np.array(val_df_padded['Ybinsym'].tolist())
eval_Ymark = np.array(val_df_padded['Ymark'].tolist())
eval_Ymarksym = np.array(val_df_padded['Ymarksym'].tolist())
eval_Ystat = np.array(val_df_padded['Ystat'].tolist())
eval_Ystatsym = np.array(val_df_padded['Ystatsym'].tolist())

eval_X = [eval_Xstation, eval_Xfrom, eval_X2, eval_Xdiff,eval_Xdiffof1, eval_Xpad, eval_Ymark, eval_Ymarksym,eval_Ystat, eval_Ystatsym, eval_Xsource]

eval_W = np.array(val_df_padded['W'].tolist())
```

Actual training:

```
# Set random seeds for NumPy
np.random.seed(759079)

# Set random seeds for TensorFlow
tf.random.set_seed(759079)

class GetLinearLayer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.layer_weights = self.add_weight(shape=(num_layers, 15),
                                             initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                             trainable=True,
                                             name='layer_weights')
        self.layer_bias = self.add_weight(shape=(num_layers, 1),
                                          initializer='zeros',
                                          trainable=True,
                                          name='layer_bias')

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs, source):
        selected_weights = tf.gather(self.layer_weights, source)
        selected_bias = tf.gather(self.layer_bias, source)

        # Expand the dimensions of selected_weights and selected_bias to match inputs
        selected_weights = tf.expand_dims(selected_weights, axis=1)
        selected_bias = tf.expand_dims(selected_bias, axis=1)

        # Compute the output directly
        outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, selected_weights, transpose_b=True) + selected_bias

        return outputs
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = {}
        config.update({
            'num_layers': self.num_layers,
        })
        return config

    
    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)

xstation = Input(shape=(None,17))
xfrom = Input(shape=(None,5))
x2 = Input(shape=(None,5))
xdiff = Input(shape=(None,5))
xdiffof1 = Input(shape=(None,5))
xpad = Input(shape=(None,1))
xmark = Input(shape=(None,1))
xmarksym = Input(shape=(None,1))
xstat = Input(shape=(None,1))
xstatsym = Input(shape=(None,1))
xsource = Input(shape=(None,1))

source = tf.squeeze(xsource[:, 0, :], axis=-1)
source = tf.cast(source, dtype=tf.int32)

get_linear_layer_obj = GetLinearLayer(num_layers=8908)

conc_linear = tf.concat([ xdiff, xdiffof1, xmark, xmarksym, xstat, xstatsym, xpad], axis=2)

outputs_seq = get_linear_layer_obj(conc_linear, source)

softmax_outputs = Softmax(axis=1)(outputs_seq)

modified_output = tf.squeeze(softmax_outputs, axis=-1)

model_custom = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[xstation, xfrom, x2, xdiff, xdiffof1, xpad, xmark, xmarksym,xstat,xstatsym, xsource], outputs=modified_output)
model_custom.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(axis = 1))


### TRAINING ###
histories = []
evals = []
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, restore_best_weights=True)
t1 = time.time()
for layer_number in range(len(training_datX)):
    print('layer_number: ',layer_number)

    current_training_X = training_datX[layer_number]
    current_training_Y= training_datY[layer_number]
    current_training_W = training_datW[layer_number]
    current_val_X = val_datX[layer_number]
    current_val_Y = val_datY[layer_number]
    
    history = model_custom.fit(current_training_X,current_training_Y, epochs=100, validation_data=(current_val_X,current_val_Y), callbacks=[early_stopping], verbose = 0)
    histories.append(history)
    if layer_number % 100 == 0:
        current_eval = model_custom.evaluate(eval_X,eval_Ybinsym, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
        print('current_eval: ', current_eval)
        evals.append(current_eval)

model_custom.save('ind_training/custom_model_sym_e100_p2_b1.h5')
t2 = time.time()
print('TIME: ', t2-t1)
```

This is the validation loss computed after training each 50 layers (there are around 5000 layers in total):

val_loss in steps of 50 layers

[image]

Regardless of this code taking 27551seconds to run (which is approx 7h30min). At the end of this training, the val_loss achieved by the model was 2.5336, which is higher than before (when training everything collectively). How is this possible? Is my reasoning wrong, or is tensorflow doing weird things of which I am not aware of?

I also tried to further train this model using the data from the sources that are not present in the validation set, expecting that the validation loss would remain the same (at 2.5336). And indeed, it stayed the same. This makes me believe that my model is correct because the current weights did not get influenced by training on data from other sources. There might be a flaw in my reasoning, the code for individual training or there is something I am missing about the fit function and the early stopping.